# remove url params from the url using jquery and push state

Tags: javascript, jquery, pushstate, pjax

Is there a way i can remove a particular params from the url using push state with out refreshing:
I know how to append some thing to the url:

```
  var url = $(location).attr('href');
  history.pushState(null, null, url + '&view=new_data');
```

But how would i remove a particular param from the url:

```
 history.pushState(null, null, url(without the &view param));
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510755.

Comment: In case you're interested, there's a powerful javascript url parser plugin : https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
 history.pushState(null, null, url.replace(/&view=.*(&?)/, '$1'));
```