# Remove url parameter without page reloading

Tags: jquery, html, url, parameters

I have this url when the user login with temporary password.

```
user.html?change=yes#passwordwrap
```

So user can immediately change the password. After saving the new password, it should remove the existing parameter in the url. Should be:

```
user.html
```

Is there a possible way to do it? Without using history because the page is first time to load and no history list. A simple approach?

Comment: I dont understand why we cant use history

Comment: @TrevorClarke, because the page loads for the first time and has no history list.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this

```
var url= document.location.href;
window.history.pushState({}, "", url.split("?")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... if you face problem with F/W & B/W button then use replaceState rather than pushState.

```
    window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/"+window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).split("?")[0]);
```

This page URL will change from:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753052/remove-url-parameters-without-refreshing-page/22753103#22753103
```

To

```
http://stackoverflow.com/22753103#22753103
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for changing url

```
window.history.pushState({ "html": "<h2>Hai</h2>", "pageTitle": "BuyOnline" }, "", '/buyonline/productview?param1=1&param2=2');
```

When back button pressed in the browser - this event is fired

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
    window.location.reload(); -- you can put your code here
});
```