# Is it possible to remove the get parameters from the referer in the header without meta-refresh?

Tags: javascript, python, redirect, http-referer

The flow with me is this we get a request to www.oursite.com?secretinfo=banana
then we have people do some stuff on that page and we send them to another site. Is it possible to remove the part "secretinfo=banana" from the referer in the header info?

We do this now, by redirecting to another page without this parameters, which does another redirect by a meta-refresh to the other party. As you can imagine this is not very good for the user experience.

Doing it direct would be great but even doing it with a 302 or 303 redirect would be better but these don't change the referer.

We are using Python 3 with Flask or it can be with JavaScript.

Comment: This answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510755/how-to-remove-parameters-in-url-and-display-it-in-address-bar-without-causing-re

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to NetHawk it can be done using history.replaceState() or history.pushState().